# How to add window.setTimeout to leadpages for a button?

Tags: html, css

I've built a page in LeadPages with a custom HTML button from Commoninja. I need the button to show up at a specific time after the page loads. Commoninja recommended adding a window.setTimeout piece of code. I've tried adding on LeadPages to their custom CSS area and to the button itself (not at the same time). Neither is working, so I'm confused as to what to do from here. LeadPages won't help with custom CSS and Commoninja can't provide any additional help. Here are the two codes:

**Commoninja button:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.commoninja.com/sdk/latest/commonninja.js" defer></script> <div class="commonninja_component pid-590d70ff-9852-4d39-80bc-8844af276d7b"></div>
```

**Widget ID:** 590d70ff-9852-4d39-80bc-8844af276d7b

**The window.setTimeout script Commoninja suggested I use:**

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://cdn.commoninja.com/sdk/latest/commonninja.js';
script.id = 'commonninja-sdk';
document.body.appendChild(script);
}, 3000); // Will load after 3 seconds
</script>
```

I've messaged Commoninja about this - they are tapped out on help, LeadPages won't help because it is custom CSS, and I've searched and searched the internet. I've placed the code in various spots on LeadPages and nothing seems to be working. I also changed the timing from 3 seconds to 10 seconds.

Comment: I am not familiar with this addon, maybe this addon requires page ready, so have you tried putting it inside document ready? `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ /*code part*/ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html where you have the commonninja button that you want to hide, add the `commonninja-hidden-btn` class like this:

```html
<div class="commonninja-hidden-btn commonninja_component pid-590d70ff-9852-4d39-80bc-8844af276d7b"></div>
```

Then add this css and javascript at the end of your file:

```html
<style>
  /* This class hides the button */
  .commonninja-hidden-btn {
    display: none;
  }

</style>
<script>
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    const btnContainer = document.querySelector('.commonninja-hidden-btn');
    // This removes the class after 3 seconds
    btnContainer.classList.remove('commonninja-hidden-btn');
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Usaid! You are an amazing person and I appreciate you so so much!!!